# JavaScript - Algorithm exercise - Dividing an array in small parts

Tags: javascript

I have this algorithm exercise that splits an array into smaller parts. This is working right, but I did not understand the operation. Could someone explain this to me in more detail. Please.

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

function chunk(array, size) {
  const chunked = [];

  for (let element of array) {
    const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1]

    if (!last || last.length === size) {
      chunked.push([element])
    } else {
      last.push(element)
    }
  }

  return chunked;
}


console.log(chunk(letters, 2))
```

It returns:

```
['a','b']
['c'.'d']
['e']
```

This parameter that in this case is the number 2, which is passed in the function, is the number of items that each array contains.

```
console.log(chunk(letters, 2))
```

I didn't understand the fact that it generated 2 arrays 'chunked' and 'last' and in the end only return 'chunked'. But I did not understand the link between the 2 arrays: 'chunked' and 'last'

Comment: what exactly you don't understand ?

Comment: The fact that it generated 2 arrays 'chunk' and 'last' and in the end only return 'chunked'. But I did not understand the 'last' array link

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of arrays. The outer array is called `chunked`. The `last` array is the last inner array up to this point. `chunked` looks like:

```
[[/*some values*/], [/*some values*/], [/* this is last */]]
```

That's what this line is doing:

```
const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1] // get the final child array in chunked
```

You then decide whether to push the current value into this subarray *or* add a new subarray. This choice is determined by whether the length of `last` is less than the chunk size — in other words whether it is full. That's what this test is doing:

```
if (!last || last.length === size)
```

The `!last` part is used to check if there *is* a `last` array because on the first iteration it won't exist yet — the outer array is empty.

For what it's worth, it might be easier to understand it you just use a simple loop that increments by chunk size:

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

function chunk(array, size) {
    const chunked = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i+=size) {
        chunked.push(array.slice(i, i+size))
    }
    return chunked
}


console.log(chunk(letters, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are three things:

1. `last` contains the last chunk, freshly taken for each iteration, which grows until it reaches the specified size
2. when `last` reaches the specified size, `chunked.push([element])` pushes a new array into `chunked` (`[element]` without an array in front of it, is a short syntax for creating a new array with a single element - and for the next iteration, that is going to be the `last` chunk. Try writing `console.log(1)`, `console.log([1])` and perhaps `console.log([1,2])` into a JS console to see their difference.
3. if the `last` chunk has not reached the specified size, the `element` is just appended to it

In particular there is one "trick", for the first iteration: when `chunked` is an empty array at the beginning, `last = chunked[chunked.length - 1]` translates to `chunked[-1]`. Unlike many other languages, JavaScript does not die or throw an exception here, it just says the given element is `undefined`, which is a falsy value and triggers the `!last` condition, thus the `push([element])` thing will run. This is how the first chunk is created.

Answer (score 0):

this will get the last element of `chunked` array , which is either `undefined` or the last chunk array

```
const last = chunked[chunked.length - 1]
```

then you check if `last` is `undefined` or is an array with size of `size` then you add new array to `chunked` array with the current element

```
if (!last || last.length === size) {
  chunked.push([element])
}
```

else , which mean that last is an array with size less than `size` , you push current element to last

```
else {
  last.push(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. a function `chunk` which take 2 arguments, an array and length of chunks
2. a `chunked` array is defined
3. using `for` loop iterating over the array
4. if the `last` array is not the last array inside `chunked` array or last     element of `chunked` array is equal to size argument, then push new element from `array` array inside another array so that it form a chunked array
5. else push the new element from `array` array to last array of `chunked` array
6. return `chunked` array

Answer (score 0):

More or less: initialize an empty array `chunked`.

Inside a loop: look into `chunked`'s last element. Is it non-existent, or is it already exactly the required length? If yes, take the next letter, make a 1-element array out of it, and append it to `chunked`. If no, then append the letter to `chunked`'s last element instead.

Run the code in a debugger, set watch expressions for `chunked`, `last` and `element` and watch what's happening to them.